# Necesito ver el registro web de una APP android para sacar una URL

Tags: android, app, apk

Tengo una app que descargue de PlayStore que tiene una función de abrir una página web. El detalle es que como la web se abre desde la app, no puedo ver la URL de la web que se esta viendo en pantalla.

Necesito saber la URL de la web que se esta mostrando. ¿Hay alguna forma de averiguarlo?

Estaba pensando algo así como ver el registro de navegación web de android, pero no como comúnmente lo hacemos, desde el historial del navegador, si no directamente como ver el tráfico del móvil, o del wifi.

Intente instalando un corta fuegos en el celular pero no me da la URL de la pagina en concreto.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. ¿Qué entiendes por *registro web*? Creo que te liaste demasiado en la explicación y al final no se entiende qué es lo que quieres hacer realmente. Por favor, pulsa en [edit]  y aclara un poco al asunto. Gracias.

Comment: Entiendo que lo que quiere es sacar la URL que accede la aplicación pero estas pensando en hacerlo como si fuera una aplicación web realmente y no lo es. Una forma para sacarlo seria decompilar la aplicación y sino esta ofuscada sacar la URL. Mediante el historial de navegación no te funcionara ya que no lo uso para navegar sino que usa un componente interno de Android.

Comment: Puedes conectar el movil a tu red wifi domestica y utilizar un sniffer para ver hacia donde se navega. O a que URL se hacen las peticiones

Answer (score 1):

Por lo general lo que yo uso para decompilar un apk es `dex2jar` y [jd-gui](/questions/tagged/jd-gui).
Entonces, descargas el apk que quieres decompilar y le cambias la extensión a `.zip`, luego de eso abre el archivo `.zip` y extrae el archivo `classes.dex.` Coloca este archivo en la carpeta descomprimida de `dex2jar`.

En un lugar vacío de la carpeta pulsa el botón derecho del ratón a la vez que presionas en el teclado shift (en Windows). Del menú elige 'Abrir aquí una ventana de comandos'.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la consola que se acaba de abrir  introduce el siguiente comando `'d2j-dex2jar.bat classes.dex'`(sin las comillas). Pulsa intro y después de unos segundos en la misma carpeta encontraras un nuevo archivo llamado '`classes-dex2jar.jar`'.

Con este nuevo archivo '`classes-dex2jar.jar`' podemos explorar el código fuente de la aplicación y ver todas sus clases con el programa `JD-GUI`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno, luego de eso tocará analizar todo el código y ver donde está la url que tanto necesitas.